# How to use jquery for scrolling horizontally

Tags: jquery

I am new to use jquery. I need to scroll to the place where the menu indicates as in this site http://www.newworkmag.com/issue1.html. If I am not mistaken then I can use scrollTo. But I could not find how to use this. Hope to get answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the jQuery [scrollTo plug-in](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) which allows you to scroll the entire window as in your example.

**EDIT:** Here's a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function)

Comment: I would also recommend scrollTo plug-in for jquery.
there is a demo: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
I think demo is as much worth as plug-in docs.

Comment: Thank you Jose and SashaN. I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrollLeft( val) for that. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/) you have nice documentation.

PS. Also there is no actual need to use jQuery for that you can use [scrollBy](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_scrollby.asp)

```
window.scrollBy( x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose is :
Scroll Follow is a simple jQuery plugin that enables a DOM object to follow the page as the user scrolls.
the link is :

http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

or

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/