# Html page load at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I need an HTML page to automatically scroll down when the page loads. So basically loads at the bottom. 
Can JavaScipt be used?

Please can you help me or lead my in the right direction.

All help is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe.

Comment: yes you can use javascript or jquery to trigger the scroll event on page load/body load.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
window.scroll(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Here is a method that worked for me:

#### Expected outcome:

- No scroll animation
- Loads at bottom of page on first load
- Loads on bottom of page for all refreshes

#### Code:

```html
<script>
    function scrollToBottom() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
    window.onload = scrollToBottom;
</script>
```

#### Why this may work over other methods:

Browsers such as Chrome have a built-in preset to remember where you were on the page, after refreshing. Just a `window.onload` doesn't work because your browser will automatically scroll you back to where you were before refreshing, AFTER you call a line such as:

```js
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

That's why we need to add:

```js
history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
```

before the `window.onload` to disable that built-in feature first.

#### References:

> Documentation for `window.onload`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

> Documentation for `window.scrollTo`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

> Documentation for `history.scrollRestoration`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function moveWin()
      {  
        window.scroll(0,10000);
        setTimeout('moveWin();',1000);
      }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="moveWin();">
<!---- TEXT HERE ---->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why would you do it twice, a second apart? (Also, why would you use an inline handler and `setTimeout` with a string argument?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the page to load at the bottom and not show the scrolling animation, why not add an anchor tag to the very bottom of the page and have your link go straight to it (e.g., `http://www.mysite.com/hello#bottom`)?  Your anchor tag could look like this: `<a name="bottom" id="bottom"></a>`

If you are wondering why I provided both `name` and `id` in this example, `name` is deprecated on `<a>` elements as of XHTML 1.0.  Until `name` is absolutely no longer supported by the (X)HTML standard you are using, it may be safest to use both `name` and `id` on anchors linking to a part of the same page.  This was noted in [W3C's XHTML 1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8).

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you could do this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```