# div containing a chat, focus on last entry

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want div containing a chat, similar to facebook.
If the text content gets longer, ther is y-scroll, but:

1. The focus shall be on the newest chat entry
2. A very long word should do a line break

[**js fiddel code**](http://jsfiddle.net/TWsqQ/2/)

CSS

```
.chat{
width: 230px;
    height: 310px;

margin-left: 10px;
background-color: grey;
    border: solid 1px black;

overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;`; for the second you need javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to scroll to the bottom when a new message comes in and you have to use JavaScript to do it (there might be a clever CSS way I don't know, though).

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (and I'd recommend you do), you can do it something like this:

```
// when a new message comes in...
var $chat = $(".chat");
$chat.scrollTop($chat.height());
```

You might want to change the selector from `$(".chat")` -- that will probably scroll *all* chats, which you wouldn't want.

You can also do it with vanilla JavaScript:

```
// when a new message comes in...
var chatEl = document.getElementById("#mychatelement");
chatEl.scrollTop = chatEl.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Evan, how would you do it on page reload? I mean when I get a new message it shows that one, with the scrolltop. But when I reload the conversation it shows the oldes message, so you either have to scroll down or send a new message to get to the newest.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar You can run the "new chat message" code when the page loads. Here's an example that might help: https://gist.github.com/EvanHahn/f3abde4987334a46bce6

Comment: Evan, I pulled it off. For first I put the line to the wrong place.

Comment: Have you tested this solution on a long list of elements? The div gets scrolled to a certain point and not to its end.

Comment: @NeliChakarova I don't think I did, sadly.

Comment: I ended up using CSS following this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ajiths4u/u9dzyvct/). Unfortunately, I lost the original so post

Answer (score 1):

For a scrolling part refer to [jQuery Scroll to bottom of page/iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe)

As for line brakes - it should be like this automatically.