# FLEX AIR scroll to the bottom of an HTML component

Tags: html, apache-flex, scroll, components, chat

I am building a chatroom using the mx:HTML component.

usually, I am able to make a textArea scroll to the last entry automatically using something like :

```
chatText.verticalScrollPosition = chatText.maxVerticalScrollPosition
```

but, when using the HTML component, using the code above does nothing and does not throw out any error, what Im I missing ?

Is there a way to do this without using a canvas ?

thanks !

Comment: This post might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe

Comment: I could eventually use a function like this but this will add extra data and for compatibility issues, I want to use only what exist for the mx:HTML component in AIR, but thanks for the help !