# JQuery: Automatic Smooth Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, bookmarklet

I have a page (that I control) that I would like it to have automatic smooth scrolling (at a controlled speed until the bottom of the page is reached).

Here is an example http://tim.theenchanter.com/2008/08/autoscroll-in-safari-firefox.html

Is there any way that could be done with jquery (not as a bookmarklet)?

Comment: What manner of man are you that can summon up code without C# or Java?

Answer (score 1):

This example will take 30 seconds to scroll to the bottom of the page.

```
<a href="#bottom">start scrolling</a>

<p> lots of content here </p>

<h2 id="bottom">bottom of page</h2>

<script>
  var oneSecond = 1000;

  $('a').on('click', function() {

      $("html, body").animate({ 
          scrollTop: $(document).height() 
      }, 30 * oneSecond);

      return false;
  });
</script>
```

You can also see

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

and

[jQuery Scroll to bottom of page/iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe)

for other examples.

Answer (score 0):

[lmgtfy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Sounds like you want it to be a constant speed - params aren't as explicit as that bookmarklet but you can [adjust](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the `easing` type and `duration` to your liking.

Then it's just a matter of binding this to `$(document).ready`.