# How To Create An Animated Scroll To Down Button With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

This script for scroll to top, how can i change to scroll down.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("#DIV1").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#DIV2').offset().top - $("#DIV1").offset().top + $("#DIV1").scrollTop()-80
},800);
```

Here DIV2 is the DIV that u want to scroll  and DIV1 is where u want to scroll .

By changing value 80 to different values u can scroll at any position

To scroll up or down increase or decrease value..

Hope works for u

Answer (score 0):

This would animate the window to the bottom of the page using jQuery

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```