# jQuery to scroll to bottom of page

Tags: jquery

So, I have two `div`s that occupies equal amount of height of page (each height=50%).

```
<div class="first" id="first" style="height:50%;">
    First content
</div>
<div class="second" id="second" style="height:50%; display:none;">
    Second content
</div>

<script>
   jQuery("#first").click(function () {     
    jQuery('#second').show();       
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, the second part only shows up when the first `div` is clicked.

How can I make it so that the page (mobile mostly), scrolls down the the bottom of the page?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is show the div from hiding and then animate the `html body` to the div's location.

Here is my jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cxjwh79v/1/

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#first").on('click', function () {
        $('#second').show();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top
        }, 2500); // Change 2500 value to time it takes to scroll
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first `div` to cover the page, and the to scroll to the second div when clicked, then add in JavaScript the height after the page has loaded

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGNWag