# Jquery automatic scroll bottom one time

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm having a trouble with my jQuery it scrolls to bottom well but I want it to scroll to bottom once not every x seconds is pretty annoying and I don't know how to fix it here is my code :)

```
setInterval(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
    'url': './message/all',
    'type': 'GET',
    });

    request.error(function(status){
        $('html').html(status.responseText)
    })

    request.done(function(response){
        if(response == '')
        {
            $('.chat-body').html('No Messages :)');
        }
        else
        {

            $('.chat-body').html(response);
            jQuery("div#demo").scrollTop(jQuery("div#demo")[0].scrollHeight);

        }
    })
}, 1500)
```

Comment: As stated in [ask], you should provide as many details as possible, like for example, when do you want exactly to scroll down? after the page is loaded? after a given event? Also, the setInterval function does just that, execute code continously, at the specified interval time, why dont you take the scrolling code outside the setInterval function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Scroll to bottom of page/iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe)

Comment: Please add commas!  And if you want it to only run once why use setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it only once, change your `setInterval(function(){` to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
```

The `setInterval(function, n)` executes the function every `n` seconds, while `setTimeout(function, n)` executes only once, after `n` seconds.