# Scroll Back to Footer after Clicking on Footer Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on my new website but I have a little bit of a problem. Let's take a look at my code:

```
$(".item2").click(function(){
    $(".item1").removeClass("underline");
    $(this).addClass("underline");
    $('html, body').delay(500).animate({ scrollTop:0 }, 'slow');
});
```

So I'm trying to have it work like this:

1. Click the link;
2. Have the page scroll to the bottom (because the page content can change the page height, so it needs to scroll back to the footer after clicking the link);
3. Stay at bottom so the user can read the footer again

My code above doesn't work for some reason. The `delay(500)` doesn't work and therefore ignores the rest of the code for some reason.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Remove the double dot. Plus I don't think it would work either, because it is not animated at first.

Comment: @QuietNaN Do we need UI?

Comment: @QuietNaN Yes, I did, the rest of the jQuery works but just this code doesn't.

Comment: @PraveenKumar nah sorry ;) thought about jQuery easings ^^

Comment: Guess you can just combine [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1891142/3880255).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code scrolls down your page after 0.5 seconds.

```
$(".item2").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    return false;
  }, 500);
});
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/qzjxt115/).