# After auto scroll to bottom of div, enable user to scroll back up?

Tags: javascript

There are a large number of this question floating around this site. None of them seem to help me though. I am trying to code a text based browser game using javascript and jQuery, as a base to build my knowledge of coding.

I have a javascript code:

```
    window.setInterval(function(e) { //This function is the only way to get the scroll to bottom to work, for me.
        e = document.getElementById('console'); //'console' is the area that outputs the system text, after a user answers questions.
        e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight - e.clientHeight; //It works without the '- e.clientHeight', but I read that this is proper.
    });
```

For the scroll to bottom function, this works very well, but how in the world do I allow the user to scroll up... to review what has transpired?

I haven't found a question asked in this fashion, so I don't believe it is a duplicate. If so, I guess I'll keep searching.

**-Edit-**

Okay... I guess my description wasn't descriptive enough, so let me try to fix that.

Here is a snipit of the first bit of my code (I know it isn't set up the best right now, but that is why I'm learning):

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
    window.setInterval(function(e) { //'#console' scrolls to bottom <-- how do I let the user scroll up to review?
        e = document.getElementById('console');
        e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight - e.clientHeight;
    });

    onkeyup = (function(e) { //On <enter> erase data in the ("input")
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("input").val("");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#console").fadeIn(3000); //A console to output answers and scenarios to

        $("form").submit(function() { //User input
            var input = $("#command_line").val(); //A nifty box to put your answers in

            var check = false;
            function check() { //If you don't follow directions this happens
            check = true;
            }


            //startup
            var yes = false;
            var no = false;
            currentarea = "Start";
            function start() { 
                while (yes != true && no != true && currentarea == "Start") { 
                    if (input == "yes") {
                        yes = true;
                        $("<p>Great! What is your gender? Type <u><b>m</b></u> for Male or <u><b>f</b></u> for Female.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
                        clothes = s_clths;
                        document.getElementById("clothes").innerHTML = clothes;
                        currentarea = "Gender Assignment";
                        check();
                        return currentarea;
                    }
               }
               start();
         });
```

So, basically, after getting the scroll to bottom working, I noticed users might want to scroll up to see what previous statements said. Right now, they cannot scroll up. If I need to make another code all together that is okay, but I cannot find one that will work for me. I've tried every suggestion I could find from all the relative postings, with no success. I have been at this for about twelve hours now, and can't figure it out by myself.

**HTML**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="banner">
            <p>Welcome To ! An Epic Journey Awaites You!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="console_wrapper">
            <div id="console">
                <p id="Start">Would you like to begin your adventure? Type <u><b>yes</b></u> or <u><b>no</b></u>.</p>
                <p id="message_help" style="display: none;">Some help, if you need it.</p>
                <!--
                PLACEHOLDER: THIS IS WHERE YOUR CHOICES ARE INPUTED
                -->
                <div id="placeholder"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="text" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" id="command_line" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/game.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
    #banner {
        width: auto;
        background-color: maroon;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: grey;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px orange;
    }
    #console_wrapper {
        border-style: ridge;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: grey;
        max-height: 150px;
        margin: 75px auto;
        margin-top: 12px;
        width: 44%;
    } 
    #console {
        display: none;
        height: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    #command_line {
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-style: ridge; 
        border-color: blue; 
        border-width: 4px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    body {
        background-color: black;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: red;
        width: 90%;
        max-height: 900px;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe

Comment: That `setInterval` function runs every `x` milliseconds, so it will continue to set the scroll continually. So when the user tries to scroll, the scroll will immediately be reset.

What was the original issue that `setInterval` resolved for you?

Comment: I was trying to get $('#console') to scroll down upon form submission. That way the user could easily see the new content. My idea was to do this, but then allow the user to scroll up if they wanted to look at what has happened earlier. I am aware that the setting does what you said. I did have it set every 1000 ms, but made it instant instead. I just want them to be able to review, if needed.

Comment: Just take the 2 lines out of the `setInterval`, You don't need an interval... Then it will only happen once and then the user can scroll up like you want.

Comment: I cannot even get it to work if I remove the `setInterval`, and there are many times a user will pass answers in this game. Will this updated code (when I truly understand it) move div to bottom on every new line of text output from the game, or is this a one hit wonder? I am looking for the div to go to bottom on every form insertion, because it will bring up the answer + a new question, then also let the user review previous sectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was:

```
$("#console").animate({ scrollTop: "999999999px" }, 'slow'); //Scroll the console to the bottom.
```