# How to Scroll Bottom using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually i am using following code to scroll on top

```
 var container = $('#items_suggession_right'), scrollTo = $(".selected");
         container.animate({scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top +
                       container.scrollTop()}, 0);
```

But i cant able to Scroll set In Bottom. Please Help me to Set Bottom Scroll using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Scroll to bottom of page/iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle code updated for scroll to bottom](https://jsfiddle.net/snehashinde/3z5bcfwa/12/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('.testwrap').height()
      }, 800);
  });
```

```css
.testwrap{
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 2px dotted #c00;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">           </script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="testwrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var time = 0; // in milliseconds
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, time);.
```

You can increase the time value to provide smoother and animated scroll to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following code to scroll to bottom of page.

```
container.animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click","#bottom",function() {
  var window_height = $(window).height();
    var document_height = $(document).height();
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: window_height + document_height },1000);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#buttonID').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Simply use this code part.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it answers the question. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$('html').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```