# Always scroll the div container to the bottom when creating child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

first these are my references

[jQuery Scroll to bottom of page/iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890995/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-iframe)

[jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page/4249365)

I create some divs and put them into a div container. I want the container always scrolling down to the newest div at the bottom.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var container = $("#container");

  var i = 0;

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    i++;

    var div = $("<div></div>");
    div.addClass("d");
    div.html("Container " + i);
    container.append(div);

    container.scrollTop(container.height());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

#container {
  height: 160px;
  width: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: gray;
}

.d {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">-- Add --</button>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

As you can see, this works fine untill I create more than 8 divs. Then the logic will break and the container does not scroll anymore.

The container should scroll to the current div with the number i (the current index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because the height is always **fixed**, instead consider scrolling with the height of **all** the child elements **including their top/bottom margin**. In other words, the height of the container if there is no fixed height specified.

To be more precise you only need to scroll with the height of all the child element minus the fixed height of the container which is the **overflowing part**. That's why your code work partially because until 8 elements you have an overflow lower than the fixed height of the container ( `8 * 40 = 320` => `320 - 160(fixed height) = 160(overflow)` )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var container = $("#container");

  var i = 0;

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    i++;

    var div = $("<div></div>");
    div.addClass("d");
    div.html("Container " + i);
    container.append(div);

    container.scrollTop(container.find('.d').length * 
                        ($('.d').height() + 10) - 
                        container.height());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

#container {
  height: 160px;
  width: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: gray;
}

.d {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">-- Add --</button>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your code works really fine but mine doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/gpy3w929/2/ but I think I got the same as you do ... any ideas?

Comment: @peterHasemann scrollTop on container not element ;) `gameContainer.scrollTop`