# jQuery: Scroll down page a set increment (in pixels) on click?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a page scroll down 150px from the current position when an element is clicked.  So lets say you're roughly halfway scrolled down a page.  You click this link, and it will slide you down an additional 150 pixels.

Is this possible with jQuery?

I've been looking at scrollTop and the scrollTo plugin, but I can't seem to connect the dots.

Comment: Love to see the code you're working with, it may be most of the way there and there's just a simple problem.

Comment: I don't have code to show yet.  As an alternate solution, I'm scrolling down to a specific #ID, but I'm trying to make this more dynamic by scrolling down 150px from where you were at.

Answer (score 123):

```
var y = $(window).scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
$(window).scrollTop(y+150);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.. for a kind of page down effect.

 `var y = $(window).scrollTop();

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: y + $(window).height() }, 600);
`

Comment: **Add** to move the scrollbar down, which moves the page up, to see a lower part of the page. **Subtract** to move the scrollbar up, which moves the page down to see a higher part of the page. (I believe the only people who get this right the first time are those who make TWO mistakes in their thinking, and they cancel out.)

Answer (score 51):

Just check this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=150px'}, 800);
    });
});
```

It will make scroller scroll from current position when your element is clicked

And 150px is used to scroll for 150px downwards

Comment: The `+=` in your answer helped a lot with a problem I was having to a similar issue I had.

Comment: Damn, this += thing was all I needed !  (me JS newbie). You should be awarded a Nobel prize.

Comment: That `'+=150px'` is super slick and it doesn't sacrifice clarity for brevity. Love it!

Comment: It may help to call a `.stop()` before `.animate()` to prevent two scroll animations run at the same time (this will cause a flicker effect)

Comment: $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=150px'}, 800); This is was all I needed!

Answer (score 8):

You can do that using `animate` like in the following link:

http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery

If you want to do it using `scrollTo` plugin, then take a look the following:

[How to scroll the window using JQuery $.scrollTo() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function)

Comment: These both seem to be set increments from the top of the browser, not from the point at when you are currently viewing.

Answer (score 3):

You might be after something that the scrollTo plugin from Ariel Flesler does really well.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: the **relative px** version of the **_scrollTo plugin_** mentioned here should do the trick perfectly. the **relative px(hash)** method will allow you to spec a dif **_left_** from **_top_** value.

Answer (score 1):

Pure js solution for newcomers or anyone else.

```
var scrollAmount = 150;
var element = document.getElementById("elem");

element.addEventListener("click", scrollPage);

function scrollPage() {
    var currentPositionOfPage = window.scrollY;
    window.scrollTo(0, currentPositionOfPage + scrollAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated version of HCD's solution which avoids conflict:

```
var y = $j(window).scrollTop(); 
$j("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: y + $j(window).height() }, 600);
```