# Best way to scrolldown onpageload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {           
        window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    }
</script>
```

The previous code attempts to scroll down after page loading.

**Is there any problem, as it doesn't work for me?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of window.onload use

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 100);
    }
```

because window.onload is fired when entire page load and document.ready is fired when DOM loads and use srcollTo instead of scroll

Comment: sorry but nothing happen, I have read that window.onload raise after $(document).ready, but I still have the same issue

Comment: may be your height is less thats why it is not working first check whether you see the scroll then you can call it other wise it won't work if you don't have scroll at your page

Comment: check this it works 100% http://jsfiddle.net/afc2e4d8/3/ you were missing this ); at the end

Comment: both works window.scroll() as well as window.scrollTo() window.scrollBy() also works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Scrolldown() {
 window.scroll(0,100); 
}

window.onload = Scrolldown;
```

Comment: they both are same. No difference

Comment: sorry it doesn't work !!!, but the following work document.getElementById('ItemTemplate').scrollIntoView(), but I don't want this one, I want to control the px position

Comment: Try this <body onload="window.location='#myID';">

Comment: @Reena that's work but in my situation I need control over px position ^_^

Comment: ok @Moatasembk my mistake, will this fulfill your requiremnet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659354/jquery-scroll-down-page-a-set-increment-in-pixels-on-click

Answer (score 0):

try `body onload` instead:

In your html:

```
<body onLoad="Scrolldown()">
```

js:

```
function Scrolldown(){
window.scroll(0,100); 
}
```

Comment: the problem is not in the event raising because I can achieve another work on page load, my problem just in scrolling down

Comment: well the above solution should work pretty good. Give it a try

Comment: between do check if you have enough content to scroll down, ie, (height of document) should be greater than (height of window)

Comment: yeah I already make sure about that, I maybe a JavaScript library conflicts but I don't any issue in my website, I'll test it on a clean website, but can it be a browser issue !?

Comment: browser compatibility I don't think so unless you are using old IE. JavaScript library: that's just plain JS so there should be any conflict with that. May be posting your whole code might help here.