# Is there a way of Scrolling to 100% of window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you scroll to a pixel number of window height, without such plugins like fullPage.js, onePage.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain Jquery:

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height());
```

This just takes the current amount that the page is scrolled down (in pixels) and adds the height of the window to it.

You might want to check out [this StackOverflow question on Jquery scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659354/jquery-scroll-down-page-a-set-increment-in-pixels-on-click) and [this Jquery documentation article on `$.height()`](https://api.jquery.com/height/), which talk about each component of this.

Good luck!

Comment: It scrolls the page to mentioned size after it (page) loads, but on mousewheel the scrolling is like usual.. See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kgdtzktL/

Comment: @EvoMedia Your question was about how to scroll to 100% of page height, not how to do it on a particular event. It's up to you to decide what to do with the code I gave you, from inserting it in an event handler to just doing it on page start.

Comment: @EvoMedia Look into onscroll functions in Jquery or JavaScript. You can use the code above as the code to be executed onscroll. Good luck!