# Correct HTML scrolling element of main viewport (+jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

When I want to scroll a website by javascript code what is the corrent element to set the `.scrollTop` property on?

Is it `window`, `document`, `document.body` or `html` element?

Does jQuery have some trick to detect the intention to scroll the main viewport and unify the calls? It seems to me that sometimes `$(window).scroolTop(value)` works, but sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the `<html>` element, aka `document.documentElement`. However if you are using Quirks Mode, `<body>` (`document.body`) represents the viewport instead. (HTML/CSS doesn't explicitly state/require this, but it is how all modern browsers work.)

You don't ever want to be in Quirks Mode, but if you're writing a script for inclusion on other people's pages you will have to deal with it:

```
var viewport= document.compatMode==='BackCompat'? document.body : document.documentElement;
// do something with viewport.scrollTop
```

jQuery uses `window.scrollTo()` instead of setting the scroll properties directly. Either way is pretty much the same in practice. You could argue that using `scrollTo` is a bit cleaner in that it avoids relying on the viewport being represented by a particular element, but then jQuery still has to use `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` to read the current value of the ‘other’ property anyway, so no big win. You can use `pageXOffset`/`pageYOffset` to read the current scroll position without relying on a particular element, but it's not supported everywhere so you *still* have to fallback to the `scrollTop` method.

Sadly none of these properties/methods have been standardised in the past. [CSSOM Views](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/) finally address this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rider to bobince's answer, which is that Webkit browsers incorrectly set documentElement.scrollTop to zero regardless of whether you are in quirks or standards mode; therefore, you cannot completely rely on his one-liner.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9248

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2891

Someone with sufficient privileges should make this a comment to bobince's answer so that it is not missed, and I can then delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are scrolling, document/Window or a division

Comment: I'm scrolling the "most main" "thing". Just as if the user drags the main scrollbar of the browser window. There are no other scrollable elements on the page.

Comment: In that case, it is window, you have to use. Why dont you post your code, so that we can take a look at it

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before as well, and it behaved quite differently in a number of browsers. I ended up using this rather horrible piece of code:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    $('body, html').scrollTop(0);

    if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.safari) {
        // Hack for webkit browsers: hide and show canvas layer so window will scroll up.
        // (scrollTop does not work right).
        $('#canvas').hide();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#canvas').show();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

However, I only needed to scroll to the top, which is easier. I'm not sure how you would do this if you want to scroll to a specific point. Maybe use anchors?