# jQuery - scrolling inside a div? scrollTo?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have a div container with list in it, only one item of this list is visible at once and the rest is being hidden (the container has overflow: hidden).

I want jQuery to show the requested items after clicking exact links:

http://jsfiddle.net/ztFWv/

Any ideas? Will scrollTo help me? I've tried this plug but no luck. I'd rather not use an iframe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ScrollTo would help, but is scrolling absolutely required? I think it's even better to just use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`

I modified the HTML just a bit to give the slide items a class and an id.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ztFWv/1/

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li id="one" class="slideItem">
            <h1>Header #1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum, ante a lacinia pharetra, ligula augue vestibulum urna, gravida placerat odio ipsum eget augue.</p>
        </li>
         <li id="two" class="slideItem">
            <h1>Header #2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum, ante a lacinia pharetra, ligula augue vestibulum urna, gravida placerat odio ipsum eget augue.</p>
        </li>
         <li id="three" class="slideItem">
            <h1>Header #3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum, ante a lacinia pharetra, ligula augue vestibulum urna, gravida placerat odio ipsum eget augue.</p>
        </li>
</div>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="one">Scroll to #1</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="two">Scroll to #2</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="three">Scroll to #3</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var linkClass=$(this).attr('class');
    $('.slideItem:visible').slideUp('fast',function(){
        $('#' + linkClass).slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you must have scrolling :)

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ztFWv/3/

Include the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) JS file and use the command this way.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#slider').scrollTo( $('#' + $(this).attr('class')), 800 );
});
```

Comment: I too think scrolling should be a last resort, unless there is a really good reason to do it. I like the compact code you wrote too.

Comment: @Neil scrolling just looks BETTER :) I want the paragraphs to slide from right side to left, no to just "show up". Indeed code rocks.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite way to do this, is to add `tabindex="0"` attribute to the tag and then call `focus()` on the element which will make the browser scroll it into view.

It doesn't give you alot of control but it's native scrolling and very smooth.

Comment: this is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [scrollTo jQuery plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

It's a doddle to use. I've used it myself for several projects.

There are other ways, such as TABS or hiding and showing divs, with or without animation. I prefer [this method](http://www.trips.elusien.co.uk/gallery/index.html) as it looks more professional.

Comment: I've been trying with `jQuery().scrollTo(itemClass);` and nothing, I know that's doodle but what I do wrong? :(

Comment: Hi, you need "overflow: auto" instead of "overflow: hidden" to get scroll bars and so be able to use "scrollTo".

Comment: Hi, I just looked at Dutcjie432's new code. This looks really neat. See it at http://jsfiddle.net/ztFWv/5/

Answer (score 0):

See these:

[How to scroll the window using JQuery $.scrollTo() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function)

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with scrolling etc. for several hours today and have come up with what I think is a neat framework for scrolling without scrollbars, similar to what was asked for here. It does vertical scrolling, either a "page" at a time or to a specific element (e.g. a DIV). It also does horizontal scrolling, either a page at a time or to a specific element (e.g. a SPAN).

See it in action at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7FFN/)

The example HTML is:

```
<p>
    <h1>Vertical scrolling</h1>
    <button class="shift up"       value="updown"    >^</button>
    <button class="shift vertical" value="updown  Av">A</button> <button class="shift vertical" value="updown Bv">B</button>
    <div id="updown">
        <div id="Av"> AAAAAAA text AAAAAAA </div>
        <div id="Bv"> BBBBBBB text BBBBBBB </div>
        <div id="Cv"> CCCCCCC text CCCCCCC </div>
        <div id="Mv"> MMMMMMM text MMMMMMM </div>
    </div>
    <button class="shift down"     value="updown"    >v</button>
    <button class="shift vertical" value="updown  Cv">C</button> <button class="shift vertical" value="updown Mv">M</button>
</p>

<p>
    <h1>Horizontal scrolling</h1>
    <button class="shift right"      value="leftright"   >&gt;</button>
    <button class="shift horizontal" value="leftright  Ah">A</button> <button class="shift horizontal" value="leftright Bh">B</button>
    <div id="leftright">
        <span id="Ah"> AAAAAAA text AAAAAAA </span>
        <span id="Bh"> BBBBBBB text BBBBBBB </span>
        <span id="Ch"> CCCCCCC text CCCCCCC </span>
        <span id="Mh"> MMMMMMM text MMMMMMM </span>
    </div>
    <button class="shift left"       value="leftright">&lt;</button>
    <button class="shift horizontal" value="leftright Ch">C</button> <button class="shift horizontal" value="leftright Mh">M</button>
</p>
```

The CSS is:

```
#updown, #leftright{
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;    
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 20em;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
#updown div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#leftright span {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

}
```

The javascript is:

```
//  See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/Q7FFN/

    $('#updown div').each(function(i){      // position the "divs"
        var $this = $(this);
        var amount = $this.parent().height();
        $this.css({top: i * amount});
    });     
    $('#leftright span').each(function(i){      // position the "spans"
        var $this = $(this);
        var amount = $this.parent().width();
        $this.css({left: i * amount});
    });     

    $('.shift').click(function(){
        var $this   = $(this);
        var value   = $this.attr('value');
        var values  = value.split(/ +/);
        var items   = '#' + values[0];
        var item    = (values.length == 2) ? '#' + values[1] : '';
        var classes = $this.attr('class');

        if (classes.match(/\bup\b/))               {    // up - Use "match" instead of hasClass() for performance
            var amount =$(items).height();
            $(items).children().animate({top:  '-=' + amount}, 'slow');
        } else if (classes.match(/\bdown\b/))      {    // down      
            var amount =$(items).height();
            $(items).children().animate({top:  '+=' + amount}, 'slow');
        } else if (classes.match(/\bleft\b/))       {   // left
            var amount = $(items).width();
            $(items).children().animate({left: '-=' + amount}, 'slow');
        } else if (classes.match(/\bright\b/))      {   // right
            var amount = $(items).width();
            $(items).children().animate({left: '+=' + amount}, 'slow');
        } else if (classes.match(/\bvertical\b/))   {   // vertical
            var amount = $(item).css('top');
            console.log("amount=", amount);
            $(items).children().animate({top:  '-=' + amount}, 'slow');
        } else if (classes.match(/\bhorizontal\b/)) {   // horizontal
            var amount = $(item).css('left');
            $(items).children().animate({left: '-=' + amount}, 'slow');
        } else {
            return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: My final word on the subject. I redid the above code to make it more efficient. See the working example at  http://www.jsfiddle.net/elusien/3MBxK/