# JQuery, how to make page scroll when div slides down so you can see it

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code which opens hidden divs on my page from a dynamic list of data, the trouble is if you click a row from low down on the page it opens the div below the bottom of the page and you have to scroll down to see it, is there a way to set some sort of anchor or get jqyer to scroll to bottom of div when it opens so the user can see it?

here is my code:

```
//CHECK IF ROW IS VISIABLE
if (!$('#'+rowid).is(':visible')) {
//HIDE ANY OPEN ROWS
$("#tableToggle tr.toggleable").fadeOut('fast', function() { });
//DO SLIDE LOAD FUNCTION
$('#'+rowid).slideDown('slow', function() { });
$("#einfo"+rowid).load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "success") { $("#loader"+rowid).hide(); $('#einfo'+rowid).slideDown('slow'); } });
//HIDE ALL TOGGLEABLE ROWS
}else { $("#tableToggle tr.toggleable").fadeOut('fast', function() { });}
```

Thanks for looking, hope you can help

Comment: Have you tried the `$.scrollTop()` method?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function

Comment: Yes does not do anything, I tried adding after slide down with the div ID and on the loaded divs if document ready but both did nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the div in question using `$('html').scrollTop()` which you can use to adjust the window's scroll bar to the correct.
To determine the correct height, get the scrollTop() property of the target element.

Example code may look like:

```
$('html').scrollTop($('#myDivContainer').scrollTop()); // Scroll to desired element
```

Additionally, you can have a smoother transition by using jQuery's animate function:

```
$('html').animate({ scrollTop: $('#myDivContainer').scrollTop() }, 2000); // Animated scroll over 2 seconds
```

Note that `.scrollTop` will return zero to `display:none` styled elements, so be sure to fire this code after unhiding the container.

Comment: I tried this but it does not do anything, I tried adding after slide down with the div ID and on the loaded divs if document ready but both did nothing           $('html').scrollTop($('#einfo'+rowid).scrollTop())

Comment: @DJ Are you sure there's an element that matches `#einfo'+rowid`? Perhaps your selector isn't finding the element. Maybe if you created a fiddle that would help us help you. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @DJ it doesn't work for me too.
try to change this code to :

$('html').animate({ scrollTop: $('#myDivContainer').offset().top }, 2000);