# Link to part of page minus navbar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem how to make a link that moves me to the part of page while taking a navbar height in advance? Since navbar is fixed to top with solid color it then covers part of div.

I simply do

```
<a href="#foo1">Right link 1</a>
...
<section id="foo1">
```

[which brings me there but looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GanfJ.png)

[and I wants this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1IMW.png)

Navbar is 64px height and I literally want that link to bring me to #foo1 - 64px

Comment: If you post your current code here, you'll get an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after more googling.

Made a javascript for scrolling effect (which looks better than just jump to position) and added offset
More info here:

[jQuery scroll to anchor (minus set amount of pixels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365091/jquery-scroll-to-anchor-minus-set-amount-of-pixels)