# why to use 'html, body' for scrollTop instead of just 'html'

Tags: jquery

I got a solution from stackoverflow to scroll to the top of the page like

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#page").offset().top}, 2000);
```

But I am not sure why to use 'html, body' for scrollTop instead of just 'html' ?

Comment: For compatibility with all browsers.

Comment: Hers the link ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some browsers apply the "overall" scroll to `document.documentElement` (the `<html>` element) and others to `document.body` (the `<body>` element). For compatibility with both, you have to apply the scrolling to both.

Comment: I'm wondering if you know which browsers doesn't support the scroll over the `body` because I can not find out anyone right now. Do you have any link which explains or gives more information about your answer?

Comment: No, sorry, but you can easily find out: Put `document.body.scrollTop = 100` in your console, and if the page scrolls then it means the browser you're on uses the body.

Comment: In addition the @Alvarao's query, I'm also interested whether one of these behaviours violates spec or if both are permitted.

Comment: This is troublesome, because callbacks then fire twice.

Comment: @Synexis You can also [debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) the callback function instead.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That is a much better solution. Mine would cause some browsers to ignore the callback. I need to not comment here when tired. Cheers. (my comment which was to immediately return the callback if the node name was BODY, not a good idea, deleted that comment and leaving this one for reference)

Comment: I've found that Firefox uses html scrollTop.

Comment: I haven't tested exhaustively, but it looks like Firefox (at version 41) and IE11 still use `document.documentElement` aka `<html>` as the outermost scroll parent. Edge, Chrome and Safari all scroll the main page via `document.body`.