# Smooth scroll step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found numerous questions and answers here on stackoverflow about JQuery smooth scroll, but I still fail to understand how it works.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

1. Why do we select html and body not just body?
2. `animate()`, animates the content of the `$root` variable, right?
3. Why is an object passed to `animate()` function?
4. What is scrollTop, a css property?

Comment: `Smooth scroll step by step` - make each step as small as possible for smooth scroll

Comment: `Why we select html and body not just body?` Some browser(s?) implement scrolling functionality on `html`, not `body`. For the rest, check animate() doc and search for `scrollTop`  (not to confuse with jQuery `scrollTop()` method)

Comment: 3: The object contains the properties to be animated, and the value to animate it to. 4. scrollTop is a property of the underlying DOMElement

Comment: **2.**: `animate` gradually changes properties of an element - in this case, only `scrollTop` (from its current value to `$(href).offset().top` in `500` ms).

Comment: You should not ask multiple questions in one. Beside that **1.**  is a duplicate to:  [why to use 'html, body' for scrollTop instead of just 'html'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222485), **3.** jQuery doc: [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) `properties, An object of CSS properties and values that the animation will move toward.` **4.** `scrollTop` is a property of an DOM element [MDN: Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Answer (score 1):

To put together some answers in the comments into a response:

1. [Why to use 'html, body' for scrollTop instead of just 'html'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222485)
2. Yes! The content of the root variable is animated - so, the scrollTop value of both html and body are changed.
3. The three arguments passed to [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) are a new value of scrollTop, which is animated to, a duration, and a complete function. The complete function is used to update the location of the window after it's been scrolled down - it's sort of cleaning up after the scrollTop change and making sure the whole window knows "Yup, we've scrolled down".
4. scrollTop is a [property of a rendered HTML DOM object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp), describing how far, from the top, a certain object is scrolled down.