# button to scroll all the way to the top with click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this javascript so that when a user is scrolling on the page there will be a small icon to the side that will scroll all the way back up the page rather than manually scrolling. The button shows fine but when i click on it it is not going all the way to the top.

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#main').scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('.scrollup').click(function () {
            $("html, body, main_container, main").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832860/how-to-scroll-the-window-using-jquery-scrollto-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in the selectors, you are missing either `#` id selector or `.` class selector, to me it seems id:

change this:

```
$("html, body, main_container, main")
```

to this and see if it helps:

```
$("html, body, #main_container, #main")
//-------------^----------------^--------these selector notations
```

Comment: That was it thanks! I guess i overlooked that. I will accept in 5 min. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh Great! and Glad this helped.